# Find all files recursively which are not in an exclude file

Tags: bash

I would like to get all the files from a directory which have a pattern and are not in a `.ignore` file.

I've tried this command :

```
 find . -name '*.js' | grep -Fxv .ignore
```

but `find` output is like `./directory/file.js` and the format in my `.ignore` is the following:

```
*.min.js
directory/directory2/*
directory/file_56.js
```

So grep does not match any...

Does anyone has an idea/clue of how to do this?

**Update**
So i've found some things but it's not completely working:

```
find . -name '*.js' -type f $(printf "! -name %s " $(cat .ignore | sed 's/\//\\/g')) | # keeps the path
sed 's/^\.\///' | # deleting './'
grep -Fxvf .ignore
```

It works (not showing) for `*.min.js` and `directory/file_56.js` but not for `directory/directory2/*`

Comment: Try to replace `find . -name` with `find $PWD -name` to see if goes better

Comment: If this were actually `.gitignore`, you'd have better tools available, in terms of being able to ask `git` to do the work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for a subset of the functionality supported by Git's `.gitignore` file:

```
args=()
while read -r pattern; do
  [[ ${#args[@]} -gt 0 ]] && args+=( '-o' )
  [[ $pattern == */* ]]   && args+=( -path "./$pattern" ) || args+=( -name "$pattern" )
done < .ignore

find . -name '*.js' ! \( "${args[@]}" \)
```

The exclusion tests for `find` are built up in a Bash array first, which allows applying line-specific logic:

Note how a `-path` or `-name` test is used, depending on whether the pattern at hand from `.ignore` contains at least one `/` or not:

- Patterns for `-path` tests are prefixed with `./` to match the paths output by `find`.
- Patterns for `-name` are left as-is; patterns for `*.min.js` will match anywhere in the subtree.

With your sample `.ignore` file, the above results in the following `find` command:

```
find . -name '*.js' ! \( \
  -name '*.min.js' -o -path './directory/directory2/*' -o -path './directory/file_56.js' \
\)
```

Comment: This was exactly the solution i had in mind to implement before to right my answer.... But i could not implement it as nice as you. Good Trick, +1 from me.